# object is black in render view but nowhere else

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I've noticed the similar questions asked but the answer to theirs is yet to fix my issue.

at the end of my project, my latest issue is the Plate pictured only shows as pure black when in rendered view and when rendering the project.

things I've tried:

- Adding/removing Material
- Changing UV
- Moving Lights
- Editing Shading Nodes
- Changing Diffuse Settings

I've attached Screenshots below and the .Blend File here:
***[Donut.blend](https://easyupload.io/kin05p)***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncheck holdout here:

[image]

Then you see:

[image]